# How to run a Visual Studio Code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, spell-checking

I just installed the Visual Studio Code (v1.52.1) extension "Spelling Checker."

Now how do I use the thing?

I searched all the menus for a command to run this extension, or any extension. I asked Google "how to run a VSC extension" and only got matches that tell me how to *install* an extension. Apparently extensions are just supposed to run themselves.

There's a whole class of extensions for which that makes sense, such as extensions that add enhancements to editor windows. But there's another whole class of extensions, like this one, for which it makes no sense at all.

How *do* you run an extension?

Answer (score 0):

This is confusing as the answer is spelled out in five-minute videos or is skirted around.

On your keyboard: `Cmd+Shift+P` (macOS) `Ctrl+Shift+P` (Windows, Linux, etc.) or under "View" and "Command Palette" opens the Command Palette so you can execute an extension's command such as "Browse Lite" for say https://github.com/antfu/vscode-browse-lite - hopefully, the developers say what the command is.

Note: `Cmd+P` (macOS) or `Ctrl+P` will search files by name. The shift is what's needed to launch the extension magic.

Comment: Some people generally don't want to watch "tutorial-videos", as these are in 90% of all cases total garbage and time wasting. I'm one of those people. OP's question is totally legit, as it seems that most documentation about VSCode and also its extension is totally outdated, incomplete or confusing. Video-tutorials should never be the only documentation, but an additional one. Unfortunately some people are just too lazy to write a good documentation. Those are the same lazy people who don't do comments withing their code.

Answer (score -1):

Open Visual studio code.
Go to extension option.
Then click on any extension.
After that disconnect your internet.
Then it will prompt for install extension manually.
Then it will ask to locate that .vsc file.
Select that and file and install it.

Comment: Welcome, and thank you for your contribution. Are you sure this addresses the question, though? It doesn't seem like Jonathan is asking how to _reinstall_ an extension, but how to _use_ an extension. I.e., extensions which don't seem to offer any user interface options once they're installed, or are not obvious or intuitive to discover.

Comment: That's correct. I have installed the extension. I'm asking how to use it.

Comment: Did you work this out? I am trying to use an extension I have installed. I can see it installed. But no way of running it. Seriously, why am I having to google this stuff?!